# Integration testing Flask on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, automated-tests

I have written a Flask Application and hosted it on Google App Engine.

How do I run integration tests in Flask similar to the handler testing mentioned in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/handlertesting).

Essentially I want to verify that a list of pages (located in the blueprints) loads with a 200 response code, before I deploy the app to Google App Engine.

my main.py looks like

```
""" main.py is the top level script.

Return Index.html at the root. 
"""

import gdata.youtube
import gdata.youtube.service
import random
import string
import logging

import sys
import json

from google.appengine.ext import ereporter

ereporter.register_logger()
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

# sys.path includes 'server/lib' due to appengine_config.py
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request, session, abort
from Routes.BelieveRoutes import believe_routes
from Routes.SermonRoutes import sermon_routes
from Routes.ErrorRoutes import error_routes
from Routes.HomeRoutes import home_routes
from Routes.BookRoutes import book_routes
from Routes.ArticlesRoutes import articles_routes
from Routes.SearchRoutes import search_routes
from Routes.EndPointRoutes import endpoint_routes
from Routes.TestRoutes import test_routes
from Routes.ConferenceRoutes import conference_routes


app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])


app.register_blueprint(believe_routes)
app.register_blueprint(sermon_routes)
app.register_blueprint(error_routes)
app.register_blueprint(home_routes)
app.register_blueprint(book_routes)
app.register_blueprint(articles_routes)
app.register_blueprint(search_routes)
app.register_blueprint(endpoint_routes)
app.register_blueprint(test_routes)
app.register_blueprint(conference_routes)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(e):
    return render_template('errorpages/500.html'), 500
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example I patched together for one of my handlers based on the [Google App Engine docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/handlertesting) and [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/).

First my handler (located at `handlers/api.py` but otherwise comparable to your `main.py` handler):

```
# handlers/api.py
# Import the Flask Framework
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
# Note: We don't need to call run() since our application is embedded within
# the App Engine WSGI application server.

@app.route('/api/v1.0/ping', methods = ['GET'])
def ping():
    return jsonify({
        'ping': 'pong'
    })

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    """Return a custom 404 error."""
    return 'Sorry, Nothing at this URL.', 404


@app.errorhandler(500)
def application_error(e):
    """Return a custom 500 error."""
    return 'Sorry, unexpected error: {}'.format(e), 500
```

Now a simple integration test:

```
# tests/handlers/test_api.py
import unittest
import json

from google.appengine.api import memcache
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext import testbed

from handlers import api


class ApiHandlerTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.activate()
        self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()
        self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()
        self.app = api.app.test_client()
        ndb.get_context().clear_cache()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.testbed.deactivate()

    def testPing(self):
        response = self.app.get('/api/v1.0/ping')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        json_data = json.loads(response.data)
        self.assertEqual(json_data['ping'], 'pong')
```

I can run tests from the command line like so:

```
python tests/test.py ~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/
```

The [test.py](https://gist.github.com/klenwell/0b9ff2a15e3cbb048494#file-test-py) file is included with [this gist](https://gist.github.com/klenwell/0b9ff2a15e3cbb048494).